# Passing Edited model to controller (Asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm trying to pass an edited model to a controller action but the model I pass is always `null`. I have narrowed down my code for testing purpose but there is still something I'm missing.

**The view:**

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Heading, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "title-field__input title-field__input__modal-view"} })
    <input type="submit"  class="form-actions__publish right" />                
  }
```

**The controller action:**

```
public void MyAction(MyModel myModel)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

The model "MyModel" has values. Which is populated in the Heading (EditorFor) correctly. If I change the value in the textbox and hit submit I successfully invoke the action "MyAction" but the parameter "myModel" is empty.

Comment: What type is `model.Heading`? What does the HTML rendered by the editor template look like? What properties, apart from `myModel.Heading`, do you expect to be populated (given you don't render input elements for them)?

Comment: 1. model.Heading is a string.
2. <input class="title-field__input title-field__input__modal-view text-box single-line" id="Heading" name="Heading" type="text" value="new updated value">
3. There are a few other properties, strings and ints mostly.

Comment: when you say empty , do you mean, the parameter of your MyAction is coming as null ?

Comment: Yes exactly. The value is null.

Comment: Invariably, when the model is null on post, that means the modelbinder was unable to bind any of the posted data, most likely due to the inputs not having the names that they should have. That said, it's absolutely impossible to tell what's going on without seeing your actual model class. Please post that.

Comment: You need to add [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] above your controller action. The view engine might be confused and i believe it is calling your get method again.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a property in class MyModel is having same name as the variable "myModel" used as parameter in Action Method. This would fail the Model Binder.

Comment: If you could show complete model and view, it would help to crack this.

Comment: @ShishirKushwaha - If it is a question (or) an assumption, use comments section to clarify rather than using answers.